# calculate the limit of this sequence $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1..}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, problem-solving, nested-radicals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

i am trying to calculate the limit of $a_n:=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+}}}}..$ with $a_0:=1$ and $a_{n+1}:=\sqrt{1+a_n}$ i am badly stuck not knowing how to find the limit of this sequence and where to start the proof. i did some calculations but still cannot figure out the formal way of finding the limit of this sequence. what i tried is:
 $$(1+(1+(1+..)^\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}$$ but i am totally stuck here

Comment: The limit is the positive root of $l^2-l-1=0$.

Comment: how do your come to this? can you pls explain a bit?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. I'm trying to find that question. There you may find all needed explanations.

Comment: now i got i think. you mean that assuming $a$ be a limit, then $a^2=1+a$. so the root of this equation is the limit of the sequence?

Comment: I've had a problem understanding this method a few weeks ago, too, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234814/limits-of-recurrently-defined-sequences) might help you understand.

Comment: @DahnJahn, thanks Dahn, perfect

Comment: i getting $x_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $x_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, so are those limits? if the sequence converges, then there is only ONE limit, why i am getting 2 here?

Comment: You get two solutions because there are two possible signs for a square root and you have both because you squared the equation before solving it - which means that the algebra cannot distinguish between them.

Comment: @Mark, thanks, beautiful sentence!

Comment: You can prove that the limit exists by showing that your $a_n$ is an increasing sequence, and also that it is bounded above by 2.

Comment: @MarkBennet that was indeed beautifully put. I thought I understand the process completely, but this gave me a new insight into mathematics, thanks!

Comment: @Dahn, the same to me.

Comment: I find disturbing that the accepted answer, even including the discussion in its comments, fails to provide a complete solution without mentioning it.

Comment: i took the torch on the way because of this equation, because i didnot need further guidance, then i accepted the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We (inductively) show following properties for sequence given by $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 + a_n}, a_0 =1$

1. $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$
2. $(a_n)$ is monotonically increasing
3. $(a_n)$ is bounded above by $2$

Then by Monotone Convergence Theorem, the sequence converges hence the limit of sequence exists. Let $\lim a_{n} = a$ then $\lim a_{n+1} = a$ as well. Using Algebraic Limit Theorem, we get

$$
\lim a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 + \lim a_n} \implies a = \sqrt {1 + a}
$$

Solving above equation gives out limit. Also we note that from Order Limit Theorem, we get $a_n \ge 0 \implies \lim a_n \ge 0$.

Comment: can you please expand your "Squaring we get $a^2=1+a$" so that i can see your steps in between

Comment: Assume that $a$ be it's limit, then inside the square root, you get the same pattern since there are infinite no of terms.

Comment: if $a_n$ converges to $a$, then $a_{n+1}$ also converges to $a$,right? if yes, then $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+a_n}$ converges to $a=\sqrt{1+a}$, is this what you mean?

Comment: @doniyor: Yes, it is what he meant. :-)

Comment: oh okay, then i have to solve the equation $a^2-a-1=0$

Comment: i getting $x_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $x_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, so are those limits? if the sequence converges, then there is only ONE limit, why i am getting 2 here?

Comment: @doniyor take the positive one

Comment: oh okay, is it because the sequence is positive right?

Comment: @doniyor yep $ \sqrt{1 + a}$ is definitely bound by $1$ below

Comment: @experimentX, i see. thanks dude

Comment: ... my please :)

Answer (score 6):

Hint: First of all show that the sequence conveges. Then if $a_n\to L$ when $n\to \infty$ assume $L=\sqrt{1+L}$ and find $L$.

Comment: Just as an additional hint: Showing that the sequence converges would be usually done by showing that it is monotone and bounded (and therefore converges to a number within that bound).

Comment: i getting $x_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $x_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, so are those limits? if the sequence converges, then there is only ONE limit, why i am getting 2 here?

Comment: @DahnJahn: Yes the OP should show what you noted him first before doing any handy manipulation on $a_n$. Thanks for noting me and him. ;-)

Comment: You need to show (using induction) that the sequence is bounded from below by 1 (if $a_n\geq 1$ then $a_{n+1}\geq 1$). edit - in fact, 0 would do, too.

Comment: @doniyor: We see  that all terms in $a_n$ are positive.

Comment: @BabakSorouh, oh okay you are right