# Prove that $1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+...}}}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+...}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, contest-math, simple-functions

So, my professor me gave this exercise as a challenge:

-First, prove that:

$$1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+...}}}}={1+\sqrt{5}\over 2}.$$

-Then, prove that:

$$1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+...}}}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+...}}}}$$

He said you need no advanced maths to solve it: you just need high-school math with no calculus...

The thing is that it's been 2 weeks now and I'm as lost as when I first saw the problem.

Can someone help me!

Comment: Hint (for the second one, though the first is similar):  let $x$ be the answer.  What is $x^2-1$?

Comment: He was half telling the truth.  You need advanced math to know that any of the expressions actually equal anything.

Comment: But notice if $1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+...}}}} = x$ then $1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+{1\over 1+...}}}}= 1+\frac 1x$.  So $x = 1 + \frac 1x$ so......

Comment: The question about nested radicals has been answered several times in the past (see the above linked question, or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267534/calculate-the-limit-of-this-sequence-sqrt1-sqrt1-sqrt1-sqrt1)).  The continued fraction has also been dealt with before (for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907083) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156140), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7266)).

Answer (score 1):

$\bullet$ Consider the sequence given by 
$$u_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{u_n}$$ with $u_0=1$

You can show that this sequence is convergent and positive, and hence converges to a real that satisfies
$$
\ell=1+\frac{1}{\ell} \Leftrightarrow \ell^2-\ell-1=0
$$
You 'll find that it has two potential solutions but only one positive you'll find that

> $$\displaystyle \ell=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

And

> $$u_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{u_n}=1+\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{u_{n-1}}}=1+\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle \frac{1}{u_{n-2}}}}$$

Etc etc ....
So this is an approach of the first "equality", but you need continued fraction knowledge to really understand and prove the equality.

$\bullet$You can then study $v_n$ given by $v_0=1$ and
$$
v_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+v_n}
$$
You can show that this sequence is increasing and bounded and with the same idea 
$$
\ell=\sqrt{1+\ell} \Leftrightarrow \ell^2=1+\ell
$$
which by positivity will lead you to $\ell$ again. And

> $$v_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+v_n}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+v_n}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+v_{n-1}}}}$$

Etc etc ..